# How can I manage discrete variables that oscillate when using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations with two discrete variables (`var1` and `var2`) that can be either 0 or 1. I'm trying to obtain a numerical solution with `NDSolve` for such system. I want to be able to manipulate those discrete variables independently, i.e, make `var1 = 0` at `t = 3`, and become 1 at `t = 6`, and back to 0 at `t =`9, and so on. I also want to make `var2 = 0` at `t = 4`, and become 1 at `t = 8`, and back to 0 at `t = 12`, and so on.

My initial attempt looks like this

```
parameters = {..., periodvar1=3, periodvar2=4,...} 
solution = NDsolve[eqx,eqy,eqz,
                   WhenEvent[Mod[t,periodvar1], {var1[t] -> 0}],
                   WhenEvent[Mod[t,periodvar2], {var1[t] -> 1}],
                   WhenEvent[Mod[t,periodvar1], {var2[t] -> 0}],
                   WhenEvent[Mod[t,periodvar2], {var2[t] -> 1}],
                   x[0] = 1, y[0] = 1, z[0] =1, var1[0] =1, var2[0] =0} /.parameters,
                   {x[t], y[t],z[t]}, {t,0,100},
                   DiscreteVariables -> {var1,var2}];
```

I figured out that this approach keeps `var1 = 1` and `var2 = 1` for every `t` (It seems like the last `WhenEvent` prevails over the previous). I tried also something like:

```
WhenEvent[{Mod[t,periodvar1],var1==1}, {var1[t] -> 0}],
WhenEvent[{Mod[t,periodvar2],var1==0}, {var1[t] -> 1}],
WhenEvent[{Mod[t,periodvar1],var2==1}, {var2[t] -> 0}],
WhenEvent[{Mod[t,periodvar2],var2==0}, {var2[t] -> 1}],
```

And finally:

```
WhenEvent[{Sin[t*pi/periodvar1] >= 0, Sin'[t*pi/periodvar1] > 0}, var1[t] -> 1], 
WhenEvent[{Sin[t*pi/periodvar1] <= 0, Sin'[t*pi/periodvar1] < 0}, var2[t] -> 0],
```

But the result were either fixed var1 or error messages. Is there a clean way to do this? (To make the point clear, my example started with two variables but I aim to progressively add more variables so it should be extendable).

Answer (score 3):

No need of help. I figured it out by myself. This will do the work:

```
WhenEvent[Mod[t, periodvar1], var1[t] -> Switch[var1[t], 0, 1, 1, 0]],
...
WhenEvent[Mod[t, periodvarn], varn[t] -> Switch[varn[t], 0, 1, 1, 0]],
```

And at the end

```
DiscreteVariables -> {var1[t], ..., varn[t]}]
```